# Update to Flex 4.9.1 breaks mobile device screen orientation

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, mobile, air

I recently updated my Flex SDK from Flex 4.6 to Apache Flex 4.9.1
Since then, my app doesn't respond to device reorientation anymore.

This is the case for the emulator as well as an actual device (I tried iPad and Galaxy Tab 10.1 )

I didn't change anything in the code, just switched the SDK and updated the sdk namespace in app.xml to 3.4.

Of course, 'autoOrients' is set to 'true' in the app-descriptor.

Any ideas why this happens? Did Apache change anything in the app-descriptor or Adobe in the Flash Player, I have to update?

EDIT: Hoping to fix this issue, I updated today to Apache Flex 4.9.1 AIR 3.8. Still no screen re-orientation. If I change the SDK to 4.6 AIR 3.4 without any code changes (except the app.xml ns, of course) it works perfectly.

I also rebuilt the entire workspace AND project from scratch on an freshly installed Flash Builder 4.7. Didn't change anything. Aargh!

EDIT2: Today I found out about the new SDK 4.10 and eagerly downloaded it. Changed nothing. Still no orientation change. Also, I installed the OS X 10.8.4 Mountain Lion on my machine, didn't do anything. I'm really getting crazy over that! I would do anything somebody would recommend me to solve this issue, as it is a terrible show stopper for me, including scratching zeros and ones on my hd by hand! Please! Give me some ideas! I'm desperate!

Comment: I thought the app-descriptor is related to Adobe AIR and I didn't think Apache Flex had any control over it [but don't quote me on that].  If I had to guess this is related to some change in Adobe AIR.  Which version of AIR are you using?

Comment: i dont think its a Flex issue but rather the AIR SDK - i believe there were changes to the orientation behavior around AIR 3.3 but my memory is a bit hazy. All i can confirm is that Apache 4.9.1 with AIR3.7 just needs autoOrients=true in app descriptor file.

Comment: @Reboog711 The version before the update (the one that worked) was: Flex4.6 AIR 3.4 (Flash Builder 4.7 standard). After the Update: Flex 4.9.1 AIR 3.4. So no update to the AIR version occurred. I don't want to use any SDK > 3.4 right now, because I want to compile this for PlayBook as well (and hopefully a proper update to 3.4 will arrive at BlackBerry in the next couple of years ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it!
There WAS in fact some problem / change in the -app descriptot file.
I don't know what is was exactly but

- creating a new app with the correct sdk / ns
- copying / renaming / editing the newly created -app.xml in my project folder

fixed it.

Nasty stuff! Couldn't make out any difference in the two xml's, that weren't commented out, but, hey! , it works now, so what ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the latest AIR SDK (3.8) includes a new 2.0 compiler, and the Apache Flex SDK 4.9.1 hasn't yet been updated for it? The AIR SDK 3.8 download page has a footnote suggesting download of the original SDK without new compiler:[download page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) (I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12 which appears to allow use of the new AIR SDK 3.8 alongside of the original Flex SDK 4.6.)

HTH

Comment: I'm still on SDK 3.4 and not planning to update right now. (Due to BlackBerry compatibility), so I guess the new compiler is not the cause. @user1134527

Comment: Yes. Let's hope that there are updates for BlackBerry, other platforms, as well.